# Facebook: How to comment on object

Tags: facebook, comments

I am trying to comment on objects from my android application
I been trying to follow this comments [guid](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graphapi/guides/comments/) but it's not working for me.

I found my object id from Facebook debugger(How do I find my object id from URL is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297797/facebook-how-to-get-object-id-from-url))
Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com/451006711598242

Now I been trying to comment on my Object in [Facebook graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Comments may not be added to a comment plugin", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

This is the url I am testing: `

> /451006711598242/comments?message='Testing...'

`
How do I use the comments api to comment on Object from my android application.

Comment: This is not an “internal” Facebook object, but an external URL (which makes it an Open Graph object). Only way to comment on those is by using the Comments plugin, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that not all the Facebook objects support comments. To see if your Object support comment inspect him in [Facebook Query Language (FQL) Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Like [Status Info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status) for example, it have `comment_info` with `can_comment` parameter that says if you can comment. If your object don't have the comment_info property you can't comment on it.