# Facebook: How to get Object id from url

Tags: facebook, object

I am trying to Implement Facebook comments api(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297589/facebook-how-to-comment-on-object) question if you got time), I need to get an Object id, all what I have is Object URL. If I will use Facebook debug, they are giving me some thing like this:
Graph API:  http://graph.facebook.com/451006711598242

I believe that `451006711598242` is my id. I been trying to do the fallow calls:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id={myUrl} but it's not working. Any ideas what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to return the object_id:

```
$object_url = 'http://google.com';
$url = 'SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url = "'.$object_url.'"';
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.urlencode($url);
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);  

$object_id = $fql_query_obj['data'][0]['id'];
```